# Simple C Program dividing a number

Tags: c, math, division

I'm trying this simple C program to divide a number..

```
void main()
{
 int i,j,k;
 i=00126;
 j=2;
 k=i/j;
 printf("%d",k); 
}
```

It shows output as 43 instead of 63.. If I put another 0 as

```
i=000126;
```

now I'm receiving error as Illegal octal digit.

If I'm trying

```
i=00000001000;
```

it doesn't show any error and gives result as 256..I couldn't understand about this unexpected output. Can any one say why it produces outputs like this?

Clear explanation will be appreciated.

Edit: If I tried

```
 int i,j,k;
 i=1000;
 j=0002;
 k=i/j;
 printf("%d",k); //which gives 500 as result
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Divide octals or integers? You cannot have leading zeros...

Comment: If you start your numbers with a zero they are in octal. 126 oct = 86 dec.

Comment: i=00000001000; may be i=0b000001000; ? What is your compiler?

Comment: As for your edit: 0002 in octal is the same as 2 in decimal, that's why 1000/0002=1000/2=500.

Comment: sorry for this foolish question

Comment: ^^ Probably, you are new to C. Don't worry... But as a general guideline, you should read the books/documentation before asking a question on forum... :-)

Answer (score 4):

In C, numbers starting with `0` are in base 8 (octal) not decimal. So your number `0126` is indeed `86` in decimal.

While on the subject, numbers starting with `0x` are also hexadecimal (base 16), for example `0x1a5`.

Answer (score 2):

Any numver literal in `C` starting with 0 is an octal number.

So `(0126)` octal = `(86)` decimal.

**Edit**

Based on the comments, have a look at the article about [positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) for numbers.

Comment: If I'm trying 050/2 it gives result as 50?

Comment: @ling.s, are you sure!? It's `40/2`. So it should be giving 20.

Comment: sorry 50/02, which gives 25

Comment: @ling.s, octal `02` is the same number as decimal `2`. See my edit for a useful article.

Answer (score 1):

00126 is read as octal number (64 + 2*8 + 6 = 86). So, 43 is correct. Write 126 if you want a decimal 126.

Answer (score 0):

When you prefix an integer with a `0` it is interpreted as an octal (base 8) number. So 0126 is actually 86.